# How to modify title of pop up window grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my grid, when clicking Edit, then it will generate a pop-up window called Edit Computer. Inside this window, you click edit button of Room, it will generate another popup window with a grid as its content. I want to know how to modify the title of the window from Edit into Room List.

Thanks.
[image: This is my UI]

Comment: One way you can do it is add a jquery event so when it is clicked, find the titlebar and do a $('#id').text('Room List');

Answer (score 0):

You add the edit attribute to the grid like so:

```
    edit: function(e) {
      if (!e.model.isNew()) {
        // Disable the editor of the "id" column when editing data items
        var nameField = e.container.find("input[name=name]");
        var name = nameField.val();
        e.container.data("kendoWindow").title("Room List");
      }
    }
```